# Cron job - redirect SCP results to a file

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have an issue redirecting SCP messages to a file when executed as a cron job:

```
(scp -q ${locationsFromTo[$i]} ${locationsFromTo[$i+1]}) >> $logFile 2>&1;
```

Is there a way to do redirect SCP Errors to a file?

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
#The script scp the files from a remote server 
#The script will run only for ($sleepTime * $maxIterations) before exiting (default: 120 iteration, with sleep 5m = 10 hours)


    declare -a locationsFromTo=("test@ssh.server.com:IN/*" "/home/in/." "test@ssh.server.com:OUT/*" "/home/out/.");
    arraylength=${#locationsFromTo[@]};
    logFile="/home/scp.log";
    sleepTime=$((5 * 60));
    iterationCount=0;
    maxIterations=120;


echo "$(date) - Script is Started" > $logFile;

for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; i+=2 ))
do
   while true
   do 
    echo "executing scp command" >> $logFile;
    (scp -q ${locationsFromTo[$i]} ${locationsFromTo[$i+1]}) >> $logFile 2>&1;
    if (($? == 0)); then 
        echo "$(date) - scp success" >> $logFile; break;
    else
        echo "scp command failed" >> $logFile;
        if(($iterationCount >= $maxIterations-1)); then 
            echo "$(date) - script is running too long. exiting." >> $logFile; 
            break;
        else
            iterationCount=$iterationCount+1;
            sleep $sleepTime
        fi;
    fi;
    done;
done;
```

Cron job results from $logFile:

```
Wed Mar 25 09:10:01 EDT 2015 - Script is Started
executing scp command
scp command failed
```

manual execution result from $logFile:

```
Wed Mar 25 13:25:58 EDT 2015 - Script is Started
executing scp command
scp: fromOUAC/*: No such file or directory
scp command failed
```

Comment: By putting the `scp` command in parentheses, you are executing it in a subshell.  You are then redirecting the subshell's  streams rather than scp's own streams.  I would not expect that to make a difference, but it's worth a try to remove those parentheses.  Perhaps `cron`'s choice of shell or of shell options is causing the difference you observe.

Comment: I removed the parentheses - the same result: scp -q ${locationsFromTo[$i]} ${locationsFromTo[$i+1]} >> $logFile 2>&1;  #But I was able to get the debug info by setting the flag to "-qv" . Now I have the debug info which doesn't makes sense :) It seems SCP it's failing authentication when running as a cron job.

Comment: When you execute `scp` in a cron job, it has no access to `ssh-agent`. That most likely the reason why `scp` fails in the cron job but not in an interactive shell.

Comment: SCP command in quiet mode ('-q') produces no output when managed by cron. I just removed '-q' flag to allow the output from "scp".

Comment: 4ae1e1 thanks. "scp" command in a cron job couldn't find the key file for some reason. So I explicitly specified the key location with "scp -i" option.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed '-q' flag to allow the output from "scp". 
(also I had to include the path to the keyfile)

Apparently scp detects when it is being run from a terminal and changes it's output to silent when it is not. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/187620/scp-report-progress-to-cron-output

Now my SCP command & script look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash  
declare -a locationsFromTo=("test@ssh.server.com:inDir/*" "/home/user/inDir/." "test@ssh.server.com:outDir/*" "/home/user/outDir/.");
arraylength=${#locationsFromTo[@]};
logFile="/home/user/logDir/scp.log";
keyFile="/home/user/.ssh/keyFile";

for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; i+=2 ))
do
   scp -i $keyFile ${locationsFromTo[$i]} ${locationsFromTo[$i+1]} >> $logFile 2>&1;

done;
```